# kotlin with springloaded on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-loaded

I've tried Kotlin with springloaded on spring-boot , eclipse for simple web.
For Java class it can do hot deploy. But not for Kotlin file.

pom.xml is almost exactly from http://start.spring.io/ except add springloaded.

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>

    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have a Hot swap solution using Gradle and IntelliJ for spring boot: https://medium.com/@bojanbelic/spring-boot-hot-swapping-a-gradle-project-in-intellij-with-kotlin-support-3559996dfafd 
Maybe you can adopt it accordingly. Hope that is helpful..otherwise sorry